# Reviewing the UI design to see if there is anything forgotten

Tags: usability, user-behavior, usability-testing, error-message, errors

I wonder if there is a some kind of guideline and/or a detailed analysis of an application to be sure everything works fine and help me to see what I have forgotten to design? The guideline/analysis I am searching for includes things like "you must supply a username to continue", "please check your internet connection", "your password needs to contain at least one letter" and many more phrases which are encountered in the app if something goes wrong and user is unable to successfully continue with the next actions.

And also I am open to any idea that helps me to prevent forgetting these kinds of things since I always feel like I do forget something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How do you make sure that your code is working at all? Usually, that's done with automated tests, and the UI is no different in this regard. Tests like these can even be written before your feature is finished (as [test driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) requires). Having tests also means you'll know if it breaks later down the line.

In my stack, this is done with [PHPUnit](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing) and [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk). The latter uses a browser like a real user, so interactions that rely on Javascript can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like this: https://www.checklist.design/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching something like https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

Its a good practice to check your screens and whole app against those 10 guidlines.

Additionally you can perform "Accessibility check".